# How to get chat_id from username in python with telebot library?

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I just want to send a simple message from bot to a user in python by using telebot library.
I wrote the code like the followings.

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token="BOT_TOKEN")
username = "@keiru"
bot.send_message(username, "Hello, World!")
```

But this code gives me error like this

> raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
> telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API
> was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not
> found

But if I use chat_id like this,

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token="BOT_TOKEN")
bot.send_message(5*91*2*728, "Hello, World!")
```

it works.

So what I want to do is to get chat_id from the username because I have list of usernames and need to send messages.

Please help me how to get chat_id from the username.
I have already tried to use get_chat() method like this

```
chat_info = bot.get_chat(username)
chat_id = chat_info.id
```

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get `ChatID` from username: It's telegram privacy policy. The only way you can obtain user's ID is from their message:

```
# Assume msg is variable holding your message object
user_id = msg.chat.id
bot.send_message(user_id, "Hello, World!")
```

Personally I always keep `user_id` - `usernames` pairs for all users that have ever written to bot in some kind of local database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this is the case we get message from others.
In that case, we can get chat id.
But what I want to do is to send message to the user with username without incoming message.